Any closed subspace of the Schwartz space is dense in its dual?
Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Schwartz space and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the continuous dual space.
Then, it is well-known that for any $T \in  \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we can find a sequence $\{T_m \} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T_m f \to T(f) \text{ for all } f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ as } m \to \infty
\end{equation}
Now, let $\mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a closed subspace and $\mathcal{V}'$ be its continuous dual space. Then,

Is it still true that for any $F \in \mathcal{V}'$, there exists $\{F_n \} \subset \mathcal{V}$ satisfying $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} F_m f \to F(f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{V}$ as $m \to \infty$?

Obviously, $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathcal{V}'$. So I wonder if weak$^*$ density still holds.

$\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$ is not a subspace of $V'$. The restriction map $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)\to V'$, $f\mapsto f|_V$ makes $V'$ a quotient of $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$.

@Jochen $\mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the inclusion is reversed when taking dual. Isn't it a standard fact?

No, Keith. This only works for dense subspaces because then (and only then) the restriction map in my previous comment is injective (and thus bijective). For example, consider a finite dimensional subspace $V$ of $\mathscr S$. Then also $V'$ is finite-dimensional and there is no linear inclusion whatsoever of $\mathscr S'$ into $V'$.

@Jochen I see...Thank you for pointing out my mistake. At least, is it true that above $V$ is dense in $V'$?

@Jochen Apparently my $\mathcal{V}$ above is a nuclear Frechet space itself. So, I guess that $\mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{V}'$ is indeed a dense embedding?

No, there is no canonical inclusion of a Féchet space into its dual.
